# Wrong DST offset in pytz for a given zone

Tags: python-3.x, timezone-offset, pytz

Mexico City's DST (Daylight Saving Time) ended on OCT28 2018 at 3:00 AM local time, that is the exact moment when clocks where moved backward one hour in time to start at 2:00 again.

When creating the following aware datetime:

```
>>>mex = pytz.timezone('America/Mexico_City')
>>>mex_dt = mex.localize(datetime(2018,10,28,1,30))
```

I get this result:

```
>>>print(mex_dt)
2018-10-28 01:30:00-06:00
```

While the correct result should be:

```
2018-10-28 01:30:00-05:00
```

because the created 01:30AM time still belongs to DST and should have an offset of -05:00. It seems like pytz supposes all countries move their clocks backwards at 2:00, but this is not the case in Mexico, where this happens at 3:00

Does anybody know how I can correct for this? suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I see you asked the same question [on the IANA time zone mailing list](https://mm.icann.org/pipermail/tz/2018-December/027322.html).

As Paul Eggert [replied there](https://mm.icann.org/pipermail/tz/2018-December/027323.html), your information appears to be incorrect.  Mexico's [official time policy](https://www.cenam.mx/hora_oficial/) indeed sets the time of transition at 2:00.  If you have information to the contrary, please share your source.

You can also see this change [visualized here](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/change/@3527646?year=2018), or read about [time in Mexico on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_in_Mexico#Daylight_saving_time).